# How can I replace one class with another on all elements, using just the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I just want to change a classname to another one.

I've tried using

`document.getElementsByClassName("current").setAttribute("class", "none");`

but it doesn't work. I'm new at javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Explanation

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not just an array of elements. That means that the collection is live, so in this specific situation, it retains the requirement that it will **always** hold **all** elements with the class "current".

Coincidentally, you are removing the very `class` that the collection depends on, therefore updating the collection. It would be totally different if you were setting the `value` property (for example) in the loop - the collection wouldn't be affected, because the `class` "current" wasn't removed. It would also be totally different if you were **adding** a class, such as `el.className += " none";`, but that isn't the case.

A great description from the MDN docs:

> HTMLCollections in the HTML DOM are live; they are automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

### Approach 1

An easy way to overcome all this pandemonium is by looping backwards.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('current'),
    i = els.length;

while (i--) {
    els[i].className = 'none';
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fAJgT/

(the code in the demo has a `setTimeout`, simply so you can see the original border color at first, then after 1.5 seconds, see it change)

This works because it modifies the last item in the collection - when it is modified (and automatically removed), move onto the item before it. So it doesn't suffer any consequences of the automatic removal.

An alternate setup, doing the same thing, is:

```
for (i = els.length; i >= 0; i--) {
```

### Approach 2

Another answer made me realize you could just continually operate on the first item found. When you remove the specific class, the element is removed from the collection, so you're guaranteed that the first item is always a fresh item in the collection. Therefore, checking the `length` property should be a safe condition to check. Here's an example:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('current');
while (els.length) {
    els[0].className = 'none';
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EJLXe/

This is basically saying "while there's still items in the collection, modify the first one (which will be removed after modified)". I really wouldn't recommend ever using that method though, because it only works **specifically because you end up modifying the collection**. This would infinitely loop if **you were not removing the specific class**, or **with a normal array or a non-live collection (without `splice`ing)**.

### Approach 3

Another option is to `slice` (shallow copy) the collection into an array and loop through that normally. But I don't see any reason/improvement to do that. Here's an example anyways:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('current'),
    sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(els), i;

for (i = 0; i < sliced.length; i++) {
    sliced[i].className = 'none';
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LHe95/2/

### Approach 4

**Finally**, you could use `document.querySelector` - it returns a non-live `NodeList` (therefore you can loop like normal), and even **has better support** in browsers than `document.getElementsByClassName` does. Here's an example:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.current'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].className = 'none';
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xq8Xr/

---

**References:**

- `document.getElementsByClassName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName
- `HTMLCollection`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection
- `slice`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
- `querySelectorAll`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: @plalx I actually didn't downvote yours - but I didn't upvote either

Comment: I still don't see the purspose of iterating in reverse.

Comment: +1, this is a valid point, otherwise it will only change every other element!

Comment: @adeneo **and** go past the upper bound of the array and throw an error, I think - since you can't modify a property of `undefined`

Comment: Yup, every other element, does'nt look like it throws an error.

Comment: Can anyone at least counter-balance the downvote on mine? It's simply ridiculous...

Comment: Huh, never realized this. +1

Comment: @plalx - would'nt it be better if they counter-balanced mine, as it actually works ?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It's specifically because `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` and not an array

Comment: I guess most of us never think much about this, as we just do `$('.current').addClass('someClass');`

Comment: @adeneo Haha I know! This problem only happens because we're specifically finding elements by class name, then modifying that class name. If we were modifying the id or adding an event handler, the collection wouldn't be modified and we wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @Ian it also won't happen since we are using jQuery

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh I know, I just meant with the OP's setup :)

Comment: @adeneo I realized it will go past the upper bound of the array only if you store the length of the array at the beginning and loop to that. If you check it every iteration, like Juhana's code, it will just hit every other item like you said. For example - http://jsfiddle.net/4JJP7/3/

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName("current")` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not an `HTMLElement`. You can access elements in the list the same way you would access an array.

The following will change the class of the first element in the `HTMLCollection`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("current")[0].setAttribute("class", "none");
```

However, you do not have to use the `setAttribute` method, you can just set the `className` property of the element.

```
 element.className = 'none';
```

Please note that `HTMLCollection` are live, wich means that as soon as the element will not have the `current` class name anymore, the element will be removed from the array, so to avoid any issues you could iterate over it using the following approach:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("current");

while (list.length) {
    list[0].className = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Another option with your new looping is to do `while (list.length) { list[0].className = 'none'; }`

Comment: What's the point of iterating if you select the same element on every iteration ?

Comment: @adeneo The iterating just makes sure it iterates the correct number of times. If you always modify the first item in the collection, that one will always be removed from it.

Comment: @Ian - Aha, I get it. You'll see the strangest things on SO!