# Javascript not displaying in internet explorer 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This seem to no be working in ie7 and ie8, is there a simple fix for this?

```
  var collapsables = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsable');

function unhide(divID) {

  // Hide previous
  for (var i = 0; i < collapsables.length; i++) {
    collapsables[i].className = 'collapsable hidden';
  }

  // Show new
  var item = document.getElementById(divID);
  if (item) {
    item.className = 'collapsable';
  }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported below IE9.

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) minimum version with support IE9 Shim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777885/get-all-elements-by-classname-and-change-classname/16778755#16778755

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
 var collapsables = document.querySelector('.collapsable');

querySelector supported from IE8

But if you need IE7, try to use dirty hack:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) { 
   document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) { 
      var retnode = []; 
      var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b'); 
      var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) { 
         var classes = elem[i].className; 
         if (myclass.test(classes)) { 
            retnode.push(elem[i]); 
         } 
      } 
      return retnode; 
   } 
};
```

You should understand - this is very slow operation. This function iterates all DOM elements

Comment: Slow when compared to the native method. But an average of 300ops/sec is plenty for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet this will get closed because it is a duplicate pretty soon, but [Web_Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552067/web-designer) has a nice working solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie).

Web_Designers solution for IE versions prior to IE9:

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
```

Usage:

```
var tabs = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'collapsable');
```