# Copy a value from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to copy a value of one span to another where the value of the first span is a number. There are multiple class string divs, i want the span value from the first one in each case.

This is my HTML structure that I have to work with

```
<button id="btn">Press it</button>

<div class="object">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="name">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <div class="string">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="name">Cheese</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="object">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="name">Biscuits</span>
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <div class="string">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="name">Cheese</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="object">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="name">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <div class="string">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="name">Cheese</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="string"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code that I have so far, and its not working. Not sure where to go next.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        if ( $.isNumeric($('div object div.header span.name').text()) ) {
            $('div.object div.children div.string div.header span.name').html($('div.object div.header span.name').html());;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback function `.text()` to return the text value based on condition:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
     $('.object > .header .name').text(function(i,o){
       if($.isNumeric(o)){
             return $(this).parent().next().find('.header .name').text();
         }
     })
});
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: What are those `(i,o)` parameters? Mind explaining? Thanks

Comment: @pablito.aven: they are arguments of callback function where i refers to index and o refers to oldtext. they are optional . check the docs http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Its copying the number to name. I need it to copy the name to the number

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thats perfect thank you very much :)

Comment: @Pedroson: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
var text_from_span = $('.object .header span.name').text();
if ($.isNumeric(text_from_span)){
  var spans_to_fill = document.getElementsByClassName('string');
  for(var i = (spans_to_fill.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){
    spans_to_fill[i].innerHTML = text_from_span;
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777885/get-all-elements-by-classname-and-change-classname)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you could give an `id` to `<span>`.
Then you could read the value as

```
var txt = $('#idofspan').text();
```

and set as

```
$('#otherspan').val(txt);
```

Comment: I'm not able to add an id as the page is not static.

Comment: You can add an id even if the content is dynamic.

Comment: @UjwalRatra: what if there are 50 template like this?? OP will have to write the code individually for all 50 for targeting based on ID. which is definitely not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwwy8909/

Goes a little like this:

With the use of an each loop and match to extract a number with any length of digit from the text.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('.object').each(function() {    
            if ( $.isNumeric($(this).find('.name:first').text().match(/\d+/)) ) {
                $(this).find('div.children').find('span.name').text($(this).find('.name:first').text().match(/\d+/));
            }
        });
    });
});
```