# Why and when for loop ignore some item with html collection

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I attached a codepen example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpmjJ

I just try to change the classname of an html collection array with a classic loop and after many test i can't figure out whats wrong and if i made a common mistake, i have always one item ignored.

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>

bout.addEventListener("click",function(){

   var newtest = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
     for (i=0; i < newtest.length; i++)
     {
         newtest[i].className="bob";
     }

 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace one class with another on all elements, using just the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510973/how-can-i-replace-one-class-with-another-on-all-elements-using-just-the-dom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `document.getElementsByClassName` which gives you a [**live NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You should use `document.querySelectorAll('.test')` instead.

```
var newtest = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
for (var i=0; i < newtest.length; i++) {
    newtest[i].className = "bob";
}
```

With live NodeList collection `newtest` is a reference to a dynamically updated collection of elements (indexed by className `test`). So after the first loop iteration when you overwrite className with `bob` the whole collection becomes smaller by one (because `newtest[0]` no longer has class `test`). It makes indices shift.

One more problem with your code: don't forget `var` keywords.

#### Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BAFyb

Comment: thx, can you explain more why this kind appear with live node list ?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` is live selector, so when you change something that not matching this selector, it will remove element from scope. So at first iteration it has 3 elements, but when you change class, it remove one element and you leave with 2 elements, so on next iteration it will take `i` element which is `i=1` so it will take second element from top. That's why you get always 1 missing. You may use `newtest[0].className="bob";` to loop through, but when you will reach last element, it will be single element, not `array` any more, so you need to use `newtest.className="bob";` for last one

Comment: thx,oh i see, getElementsByClassName seems faster by far than querySelectorAll in all jsperf test but for dom manipulation in loop, querySelectorAll is the best way to do it thats right?

Comment: @albator yes, `querySelector` is more flexible