# How to Find and replace class with javascript (No JQ)

Tags: javascript, css

**For example:** i have `<div class="oneClass twoClass colorRed">Content</div>` and i want to find the `color*` class and replace the color part "Red" with the new value "Blue" or "Yellow" for example so it would be "`colorBlue`" now...

How do i do that with Javascript only ?

Thanks!

Update:
This isn't my question: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: First Google result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: [Read this.][1] 


Or something else you're looking for.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510973/how-can-i-replace-one-class-with-another-on-all-elements-using-just-the-dom#answer-16511067

Comment: Why so much unuseful comments. let the right guy that understand the question answer just like Tomek did and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var node = document.getElementById('someDiv');
node.className = node.className.replace(/color.*/, 'colorBlue');
```

```css
/* This css snippet will allow to see 
 * element's classes rendered with the html ;)*/
div:after {
  content: attr(class);
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="someDiv" class="oneClass twoClass colorRed">Content</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! exactly what i meant.

Comment: The problem with that is that it works only if the class i'm changing is the last one, but if it is the first one it will erase all other classnames... Any Ideas?

Comment: To solve the problem i have changed it to: /color[A-Z][a-z]+/g

Answer (score 0):

Select the div tag.
Get the element.className of the div tag so you have the classnames as a string.
Use a regular expression to replace the colorRed part of the string with colorBlue.
use .className again to set the class of the div to your editted string.
If you don't have to support IE, you can use element.classList and its methods.